# Android Layout Design Specific Custom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am Stuck at place where i want to developer custom layout in android,
 please Suggest that how can i achieve layout like this which technology should i use ,
 I want to develop application like Booking of Seats in bus or Some thing like that Please Guide which way i go like on XML,openGL , 
Canvas Please guide me
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to interact (handle click or touch) with every view marked with a number I would strongly recommend using XML. Using OpenGL or Canvas would add plenty of time to achieve a good interaction. Creating your layout in XML will be the hardest part, but after that you'll be able to interact with every view setting regular *View.OnClickListener* or *TouchListener*.

Hope this suggestion helps.

Comment: hi Buckeridge, thanks for quick Response i am  friendly with the Xml and  View.OnClickListener or TouchListeners but can you Please Guide me how to achieve above image in XMl

Comment: Start from bottom to top, and from center to the sides using a RelativeLayout. You'll need to get the resources for the tricky triangular (and those more complex like the streets, the cars and the trees) shapes. It's gonna take you some time to achieve that, but don't dispear.

Comment: Buckeridge : Thanks , in above image numbered Boxes and the layout is my primary target to achieve please guide

Comment: Try the following: -Adjust the image to the tablet resolution (I assume you're using a tablet cause in a regular device would be so hard to interact). -Set the image in a fullscreen ImageView. -Calculate the position for each "seat" in percent of screen width and height so its independent of the device (you can use Photoshop for this). Try validating the coords of MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and match them with every "seat" using IF statements. *Is not an easy task either way*